# How can I rescue an infected sony vaio bios?

Tags: bios

I am trying to rescue a Sony Vaio laptop which I believe has an infected bios.
I have autonuked the hard disk and installed a fresh Windows 7 but the keyboard types random combinations of letters and numbers depending on which keys I press. The delete key does not work. If I plug in an external keyboard I can type normally. I have flashed the bios but the problem persists. I have uninstalled the keyboard and reinstalled the keyboard in Device Manager Please can you help?

Comment: Replace the physical keyboard and keep beer away from the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, it could as well be a hardware bug, so you should try using it with an external keyboard first to check that.

If you can rule that out, it could be a bootkit. If flashing the BIOS didn't help and you want to be 100% sure, download the latest BIOS flash from Sony and reinstall your BIOS completely via USB. That should pretty much do it. Flashing alone doesn't help if the reset / update is corrupted as well.

Comment: Why a boot kit over a hardware problem?

Comment: Well even tho I'm not a help desk professional, keyboards are pretty simple and among my vast amount of past machines, not a single keyboard has failed from the hardware side. You really need to screw around to ruin them. I did add the suggestion to try an external one first, tho.

Comment: Yeah. Just seems odd behavior for a boot kit. Like the idea of testing with an external keyboard.

Comment: Non working keys or erratic behavior could be the result of a hardware problem, maybe caused by spilling something on the keyboard. See for example http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/keyboard-going-crazy-after-spilling-my-drink.186609/. I find this more likely than malware which sits deep in the system just to annoy the user by causing erratic behavior for only the built in keyboard.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich And this is why I have a ThinkPad :-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U5n2WaMMHo

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing and reseating the cable for the actual keyboard and see if the problem exist exactly. I would recommend a keyboard replacement.